# Physics driven character movement

Tags: animation, game-engine, physics

I've got an armature with a collision-mesh hooked up to it. The idea is now that by only using animations the character would move around in the world. For example pushing off a wall in Zero-G would propel the character in the opposite direction.

[image: Armature with collision mesh]

[image: Explanation]

I haven't figured it out yet so I'm hoping that I've explained it good enough.